# Url Masking directory

Tags: url, masking

I want to mask a whole directory and their files in order to show just the main URL

From:

```
www.domain.com/directoryX/directoryY/index.html or www.domain.com/directoryX/index.php`
```

To:

```
www.domain.com
```

I don't know how to do this with .htaccess, any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
      if(history.replaceState) history.replaceState({}, "", "/");
      </script>
```

**Note : where / is the path u want to show.**

it shows the url like `mysite.com`   no matter which link i have clicked. but i have a problem with this code while reloading the page the complete url with query string blink into address bar.